# WMTS in OpenLayers unable to zoom into detail

Tags: openlayers, wmts

Based on the OpenLayers example at 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html?q=wmts

I'm trying to load a WMTS in my own example here 
https://codepen.io/vishnu4/pen/EMBZdp?editors=1010 , but it really only seems to show just one large image that I can't zoom into to see more details.  If I load it in QGIS, there are all sorts of other features that I'm not seeing.

How do I zoom into this WMTS to show the QGIS level of detail instead?

[image: qgis image]

Comment: you need to load the ol/format/WMTSCapabilities.js file first see > https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/format/WMTSCapabilities.js which uses other javascript libraries

Comment: i'm loading the entire ol library https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js, which includes the data in that file.  You can see i'm calling the format.WMTSCapabilities as a parser at the top of the js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be due to the WMTSCapabilities.xml suggesting the only matrix is at zoom level 7, which is incorrect, there is data from 7 to 17.

[image]

A simple workaround is to define the source as an XYZ

```
          source: new ol.source.XYZ({
              url: 'https://www.ngi.be/cartoweb/1.0.0/topo/default/3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.png',
              minZoom: 7,
              maxZoom: 17
          })
```

Also there is no problem using `.optionsFromCapabilities()` with EPSG:3812

Comment: XYZ definitely fixes it for me, thanks!  I couldn't get optionsFromCapabilities to work with 3812 though, not sure why.